# Way to get distinct count from varstocase variable

Tags: spss

Is there any way to count original values distinct values, when the variable has been created by varstocases?

The variable which is varstocases is multi answer, therefore I got it coded as Var_1 to Var_X, like on that sample screenshot (note that in SPSS they're labeled of course)

[image: table description]

I make standard `varstocases`

```
        VARSTOCASES /make Var_1_product from
Var1_1_1
Var1_1_2
Var1_1_3
Var1_1_4
Var1_1_5
Var1_1_6
```

and then obviously when I split them by country, or by product category, like

```
CTABLES
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=Var_1_product Country DISPLAY=DEFAULT
  /TABLE Var_1_product BY Country [C][COUNT F40.0]
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=Var_1_product ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=Country ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=EXCLUDE
  /CRITERIA CILEVEL=95
  /TITLES TITLE="Var_1 product by country".
```

It gets total of, for instance 110, when there are N = 55, because of varstocases. How to get real count, of the original "N", when my variable is split into few columns.

Comment: Why not do this analysis BEFORE the casestovars? you should hold the re-structured data in a different dataset (use `dataset name orig. dataset copy restr. dataset activate restr. casestovars......`), and then use each for the relevant analyses.